# Remove every other newline

Tags: regex, excel, formatting

I have a list of data in text format that looks as follows

`Name1 Name2`

`location job date amount`

`Name1 Name2`

`location job date amount`

`Name1 Name2`

`location job date amount`

I need to somehow make this into

`Name1 Name2 location job date amount`

...

I figure there has got to be a way to grab every other newline with either regex or excel. I could write a python script but this file has been a pain and was hoping there would be an easier way to do it.

EDIT: adding what I've tried below:

Sorry, I should have included some code... I tried

```
([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n
```

in regex, but that groups the two lines together, I basically would like to grab only the newline between the groups. I have also tried doing this in excel systematically but it doesn't continue to grab every other cell when I drag the box down. It changes from every other cell in the column to every cell once I try to extrude it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included some code...

I tried ([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n in regex, but that groups the two lines together, I basically would like to grab only the newline between the groups.

I have also tried doing this in excel systematically but it doesn't continue to grab every other cell when I drag the box down. It changes from every other cell in the column to every cell once I try to extrude it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using .Net regex flavoring (should be the same for VBA, but I didn't check), I came up with the following:

```
Pattern = "([^\n]*)(\n)([^\n]*(\n|\z))"
Replacement = "$1$3"
```

Basically, catching the first NewLine character in the second capture group and then not returning it in our replacement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would this require much modification to remove all lone CR? I have a file with intermittent CR and CRLF...somehow...so that I have CR CRLF CR CRLF between many bits of actual text (spaces added for clarity)